# Declaring a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm close to going nuts! I'm somehow really struggling to get the range object right. If I'm entering this, I always get an error message:

```
Dim ValidationRange As Range    
Set ValidationRange = Tabelle3.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 1))
```

But if it enter the the range like this, everything is fine:

```
Dim ValidationRange As Range    
Set ValidationRange = Tabelle3.Range("a1:a4")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening when you declare your range like this

```
Set ValidationRange = Tabelle3.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 1))
```

Is really this

```
Set ValidationRange = Tabelle3.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1))
```

Because a `cells` object is just like a `Range` object except where a `Range` can by many cells, `cells` can only be one. Regardless, they are declared with respect to a parent object (sheet). If one is not specified `ActiveSheet` is assumed. If `Tabelle3` is not your current active sheet then something is going to go wrong because a range in `Tabelle3` cannot contain cells from another sheet. It doesn't make sense.

This will work because the parent of `Cells` is the same parent as the `Range`:

```
With Tabelle3
  .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(4, 1))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, I was now able to solve it like this! 

    Range(Tabelle3.Cells(7, 12), Tabelle3.Cells(16, 12))

Comment: @fydelio Be sure to have `Tabelle3` on both the range and the cells otherwise you're just going to be stuck in the same boat again but for the opposite reason. `Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Cells(7, 12), Tabelle3.Cells(16, 12))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using your code without using Tabelle3. prior to your range statement.

```
Dim ValidationRange As Range
Set ValidationRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 1))
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

you refer the range to the table but not the cells. try this:

```
With Tabelle3
  .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 1))
End With
```